# How to create SAS token in Postman to use with Service bus?

Tags: postman, azureservicebus

Base on this Microsoft documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/eventhub/generate-sas-token

the code for nodejs is:

```
function createSharedAccessToken(uri, saName, saKey) { 
if (!uri || !saName || !saKey) { 
        throw "Missing required parameter"; 
    } 
var encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri); 
var now = new Date(); 
var week = 60*60*24*7;
var ttl = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000) + week;
var signature = encoded + '\n' + ttl; 
var signatureUTF8 = utf8.encode(signature); 
var hash = crypto.createHmac('sha256', saKey).update(signatureUTF8).digest('base64'); 
return 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encoded + '&sig=' +  
    encodeURIComponent(hash) + '&se=' + ttl + '&skn=' + saName; 
 }
```

And I was trying it on Postman, in case anyone need help with it.  This is the code that works for me under the Pre-request Script using Postman

```
var namespace = pm.collectionVariables.get("serviceNamespace");
var uri = "https://" + namespace + ".servicebus.windows.net/adfTest/messages";
var saName = pm.collectionVariables.get("SharedAccessKeyName");
var saKey = pm.collectionVariables.get("SharedAccessKeySend");

var sasToken = createSharedAccessToken(uri, saName, saKey);

console.log(sasToken);
pm.collectionVariables.set("SasToken", sasToken);

function createSharedAccessToken(uri, saName, saKey) { 
    if (!uri || !saName || !saKey) { 
            throw "Missing required parameter"; 
        } 
    var encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri).toLowerCase(); 
    var now = new Date(); 
    var week = 60*60*24*7;
    var ttl = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000) + week;
    var signature = encoded + '\n' + ttl;     
    var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signature, saKey);
    var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
    return 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encoded + '&sig=' +  
        encodeURIComponent(hashInBase64) + '&se=' + ttl + '&skn=' + saName; 
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Under you collection create the variables:
   [image]

Get the values from Azure portal - Service bus
serviceNamespace, SharedAccessKey, SharedAccessKeyName

2. Add the code under Pre-request Script
   [image]

   ```
   var namespace =      pm.collectionVariables.get("serviceNamespace");
   var uri = "https://" + namespace + ".servicebus.windows.net/adfTest/messages";
   var saName = pm.collectionVariables.get("SharedAccessKeyName");
   var saKey = pm.collectionVariables.get("SharedAccessKeySend");

   var sasToken = createSharedAccessToken(uri, saName, saKey);

   console.log(sasToken);
   pm.collectionVariables.set("SasToken", sasToken);

   function createSharedAccessToken(uri, saName, saKey) { 
       if (!uri || !saName || !saKey) { 
               throw "Missing required parameter"; 
           } 
       var encoded = encodeURIComponent(uri).toLowerCase(); 
       var now = new Date(); 
       var week = 60*60*24*7;
       var ttl = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000) + week;
       var signature = encoded + '\n' + ttl;     
       var hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(signature, saKey);
       var hashInBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.stringify(hash);
       return 'SharedAccessSignature sr=' + encoded + '&sig=' +  
           encodeURIComponent(hashInBase64) + '&se=' + ttl + '&skn=' + saName; 
   }
   ```

**Note**: the `adfTest` part is the name of the topic, it should be replace by your topic name

```
var uri = "https://" + namespace + ".servicebus.windows.net/adfTest/messages";
```

- Under Authorization use the sasToken variable:
  [image]
- Select API key from the dropdown menu.
- Key = Authorization
- Value = {{SasToken}} <-- this is the variable name
- Add to = Header

4. Create a post:
   [image]

These are the requirements for the post

```
     POST https://<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net/<yourentity>/messages
    Content-Type: application/json
    Authorization: SharedAccessSignature sr=https%3A%2F%2F<yournamespace>.servicebus.windows.net%2F<yourentity>&sig=<yoursignature from code above>&se=1438205742&skn=KeyName
    ContentType: application/atom+xml;type=entry;charset=utf-8
```

The URL should look like:
https://.servicebus.windows.net//messages

under Authorization inherit auth from parent:
[image]

this is gonna add Authorization header with the SAS token generated by the pre-request Script under the collection

Add the other headers:
[image]

6. Put the message in the body:
   [image]

This could be any json data