# Postman SAS token authorization failures

Tags: azure-eventgrid, postman-pre-request-script

I'm having failures with the SAS token I'm generating to put an event on an Event Grid Topic via Postman. The error:

```
"code": "Unauthorized",
"message": "Invalid signature. The request authorization signature was not signed with any of the topic keys. Report '81fb0163-1d5e-4fc6-9a58-1706a600a343:6:6/29/2023 6:55:25 PM (UTC)' to our forums for assistance or raise a support ticket."
```

The pre-request script to generate the token (adapted from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/authenticate-with-access-keys-shared-access-signatures#generate-sas-token-programmatically and [How to create SAS token in Postman to use with Service bus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69383150/how-to-create-sas-token-in-postman-to-use-with-service-bus)):

```html
var resource = pm.collectionVariables.get("eventTopicEndpoint");
var key = pm.collectionVariables.get("sharedAccessKeyValue");

var sasToken = createSharedAccessToken(resource, key);
pm.collectionVariables.set("sasToken", sasToken);

function createSharedAccessToken(resource, key) { 
  if (!resource || !key) { 
    throw "Missing required parameter"; 
  } 
  
  var now = new Date(); 
  var week = 60*60*24*7;
  var ttl = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000) + week;
  var expiration = new Date();
  expiration.setTime(now.getTime() + ttl);
  
  var encodedResource = encodeURIComponent(resource);
  var encodedExpiration = encodeURIComponent(expiration.toISOString());
  var unsignedSas = `r=${encodedResource}&e=${encodedExpiration}`;
  var signatureBase64 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(unsignedSas, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
  var encodedSignature = encodeURIComponent(signatureBase64);

  return `SharedAccessSignature ${unsignedSas}&s=${encodedSignature}`;
}
```

The key that is being used is one of the topic access keys found in the Azure Portal for the topic. The value was copied and put into a collection variable named "sharedAccessKeyValue". Any help solving why the "signature was not signed with any of the topic keys" would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by replacing:

```
var signatureBase64 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(unsignedSas, key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

With:

```
var keyFromBase64 = CryptoJS.enc.Base64.parse(key);
var signatureBase64 = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(unsignedSas, keyFromBase64).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
```

Credit to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1321255/sas-token-authorization-failures-in-postman?page=1&orderby=Helpful&comment=answer-1279748#newest-answer-comment